# Количество вызовов onCreateView фрагментов в ViewPager не соответствует действительности

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Tab 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Tab 2");
        adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Tab 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Tab 2");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<String>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Данный метод вызывается, почему то только два раза. Не совсем понятно почему.

CheeseListFragment.java

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_cheese_list, container, false);
           // setupRecyclerView(rv);
            return rv;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо вы ожидаете, что все фрагменты (в вашем примере 4) будут созданы сразу?

Если так, то вы не поняли, что ViewPager создаёт только те фрагменты, кои сейчас отображает + те, что слева и справа от отображаемого.
Т.к. по умолчанию отображается первый фрагмент, то создаются соответственно только он и следующий.
Отсюда и срабатывание методов жизненного цикла только 2 фрагментов из 4.

Comment: Как же все оказывается просто)

Comment: Так же можно изменить это поведение при помощи метода [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

Comment: @ЮрийСПБ Каким образом можно получить доступ к тому фрагменту, который висит в памяти, то есть тот, который следующий? У меня в `onCreateView` заданы значения, и по причине того что фрагмент уже создан и хранится в памяти его метод `onCreateView` не срабатывает.

Comment: @McDaggen, это очень сложный вопрос. Описывать что как и почему - несколько страниц мелкого текста. Кратко - можно попробовать хранить в адаптере ViewPager ссылки на фрагменты.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб А если не получать доступ, а например обновлять его там же в памяти? Например я вношу изменения в текущем фрагменте, и мне нужно чтобы следующий который в памяти тоже обновился

Comment: @McDaggen, много как можно это сделать. Например писать в префы и слушать во фрагментах их изменение. Либо подписать все фрагменты на цепочку событий использую RxJava. Многое от задачи вашей зависит

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Гляньте пожалуйста если не сложно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/672278/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-fragment-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-viewpager

Comment: В комментариях там написали подходящий вариант