# Обновление fragment которые в памяти ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Приветствую, я использую `PlaceholderFragment`, в общем у меня более 40 фрагментов с одинаковыми `View` элементами которые заполняются из БД. Я реализовал `DialogFragment` в качестве окна настроек, и через него меняю размер текста моих `View` элементов, записываю эти значения в `SharedPreferences` при уничтожении `DialogFragment`, получаю эти значения в методе `onCreateView` моих фрагментов. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда я меняю размер текста, то в текущем фрагменте изменения происходят сразу, но как я пролистаю раз, там изменений еще не бывает, нужно пролистать `ViewPager` дважды чтобы изменения вступили в силу во всех фрагментах. Я так понимаю это происходит по причине того, что `ViewPager` хранит в памяти предыдущий, текущий и следующий фрагменты. Вопрос, как мне при изменении размера текста вместе с этим перегрузить и те фрагменты, которые хранятся в памяти `ViewPager`? Или куда мне поместить получение значении из `Preferences` чтобы изменения попадали и в те фрагменты, которые хранятся в памяти? Метод `onCreateView` в котором я их получаю и передаю моим `View` элементам срабатывает только через фрагмент.

Comment: Возможно вам поможет [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html). Подписывайтесь на изменения во фрагменте и меняйте размер шрифта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом, в адаптере `ViewPager` добавил:

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

А в методе `onDissmis` `DialogFragment` когда сохраняются в `SharedPreferences` выбранные значения размера шрифта добавил:

```
myViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```